# Does Magnus Carlsen have any openings/opening variations named for him?

Tags: opening, carlsen

Does Magnus Carlsen have any openings/opening variations named for him?

The last world champion I know of to have an opening variation named for him was Anatoly Karpov (e.g. Caro-Kann, Karpov Variation or Karpov Variation in the Ruy Lopez).

Comment: Facepalm--I totally forgot Fischer's many variations... anyway, question still remains.

Comment: Yes, `1.[insert any move]` :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the old days variations were named after players who did serious theoretical work and/or played one line consistently over a longer period.

As openings got more and more analyzed it got increasingly more difficult to find new variations comparable to those old masters. Nowadays the top players might find a novelty around move 20 or so. If you want, you could call those lines *variation* and credit them to the player. I am sure some websites do just that, but personally I see a big difference between say the Najdorf variation and those side lines.

So yes, probably somebody somewhere called something a Carlsen variation, but whether you consider it a variation is up to you. Also, perhaps it needs some more time until a line is called variation and maybe in 10 years people will agree to call a line Carlsen variation.

Answer (score 6):

The following variation:

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nc3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Qxd4 Nc6 5.Qd2!? Nf6 6.b3!?
```

Was recently introduced by Carlsen in [Carlsen - Wojtaszek, Gashimov Memorial april 2018](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1918363). It's currently becoming popular with other grandmasters and [Chess Publishing has started referring to it as the Carlsen Variation](https://www.chesspublishing.com/content/5/index.htm).

If it turns out to be more than a fad for this season, I think that name will stick. Nobody played it before and the world champion introduced it to win a game in a top tournament.

Answer (score 4):

Also, after Karpov, Kasparov has a variation in the Queen's Indian (1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nf3 b6 4.Nc3) and Kramnik has a weird variation in the Sicilian (1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 e6 3.c4)
I didn't find anything for Anand and Carlsen, though.